# VB Overwrite text file with data from other text file

Tags: vb.net, streamreader

So I've two text files showInfo, which holds information regarding theater plays.

When the program runs I choose a month (e.g. september,november) and the program opens showInfo.txt and looks line by line for the chosen month. If the line it's checking doesn't match the chosen month, that text gets saved to temp.txt. When found, it loads the next two lines which hold the title and the description which I can edit/update and then click save.

So then I have two files, one which holds all the original information, and one which holds the edit information as well as the months that lead up to the chosen month. I was wondering if there was a way to combine these two together and keep the updated information?

```
Try
    Dim tempFile As StreamWriter = New StreamWriter("..\..\resources\temp.txt")
    Dim showFile As StreamReader = New StreamReader("..\..\resources\showInfo.txt")
    Do
        With showFile
            Dim month As String = showFile.ReadLine, title As String = showFile.ReadLine, des As String = showFile.ReadLine
            MsgBox("LOOKING FOR " & showTitle & " READ " & title & " FROM FILE.")
            If title = showTitle Then
                MsgBox("Found" & showTitle)
                found = True

                tempFile.WriteLine(cmbMonth.Text)
                tempFile.WriteLine(txtTitle.Text)
                tempFile.WriteLine(txtDescription.Text)

            Else
                tempFile.WriteLine(month)
                tempFile.WriteLine(title)
                tempFile.WriteLine(des)

            End If

            If found Then
                File.Copy("temp.txt", "ShowInfo.txt", True)
            End If

            'MsgBox("Are you sure you want to save this?.", MsgBoxStyle.YesNo, "Warning!")
            'tempFile.Close()
            'MsgBox("Your file has been successfully saved.", MsgBoxStyle.Information, "Successfully saved.")

        End With
    Loop Until found

    tempFile.Close()
    showFile.Close()
```

Comment: If you loop until the end of the input file instead of until the line matches, then you will end up with all the data from the input file in the output file. Is that what you're trying to do?

Comment: If you aren't set on a text file, there are other solutions such as xml or binary if the file doesn't need to be human readable. I consider these options to have more straightforward implementations than text.

Answer (score 0):

You could move the copy operation outside the loop. That way, once you've found the lines you're looking for and replaced them, you still copy the rest of the data to temp.txt. Modify your code to something like the following. Please forgive me for my possibly butchered Basic ... it's been a while:

```
While Not ShowFile.EndOfStream
    Dim month As String = showFile.ReadLine
    Dim title As String = showFile.ReadLine
    Dim des As String = showFile.ReadLine
    MsgBox("LOOKING FOR " & showTitle & " READ " & title & " FROM FILE.")
    If title = showTitle Then
        MsgBox("Found" & showTitle)

        tempFile.WriteLine(cmbMonth.Text)
        tempFile.WriteLine(txtTitle.Text)
        tempFile.WriteLine(txtDescription.Text)
    Else
        tempFile.WriteLine(month)
        tempFile.WriteLine(title)
        tempFile.WriteLine(des)
    End If
End While
tempFile.Close()
showFileClose()

' now copy
File.Copy("temp.txt", "ShowInfo.txt", true)
```

One danger here is that if `showTitle` exists in more than one month, you're going to change it all those places. If you don't want to do that, then use a `found` flag and change your code slightly:

```
    if (Not found) And (title = showTitle) Then
        MsgBox(...)
        found = True
        ...
```

Comment: Sorry Jim, I have gotten further with the edited 'temp.txt' file displaying the new text along with all the rest of the text. However, I'm running into another problem where an  'unhandled exception' is occuring. The message is saying that it cannot find the 'temp.txt' file. Any ideas how to get around this? I really want to over-write the 'showInfo.txt' file with the edited 'temp.txt' file, is there a way of doing this?

Comment: @NoelRyan: You probably want to use `"..\..\resources\temp.txt"` rather than `"temp.txt"` and be sure to change the path for `"ShowInfo.txt"`, too.